« I would be happy to [do x] » dans un mail professionnel
En anglais, assez souvent, on voit quelque chose comme

...I would be happy to [do x] if necessary/if you need/etc.

comme un moyen de dire

Et si nécessaire, je suis prêt et capable [de faire X] si cela facilite les choses/si vous le souhaite/etc.

C'est-à-dire, je ne suis pas vraiment heureux de faire quelque chose, mais je veux exprimer, d'une façon polie, que de faire cette chose me paraît raisonnable et que je peux le faire si besoin.
Exemple concret:

Je suis conscient que cette requête nécessitera un peu de recherche de votre part, et je serais donc heureux de payer des frais supplémentaires pour votre temps.

Mais, je trouve que ça sonne faux (mais j'ai tort, tout simplement, peut-être), et en anglais c'est mieux:

I am aware that this request will require some research on your end, et I would thus be happy to pay extra fees for your time.

Concrètement, est-ce que je peux traduire littéralement et dire « heureux de... » dans ce contexte, ou y a-t-il un autre moyen d'exprimer ce que j'ai décrit ci-dessus ?

Dans ces situations on emploie souvent l'expression "je me tiens à votre disposition pour..." afin de signifier qu'on est prêt à faire quelque chose à la demande de son interlocuteur. Remarque : "Example concrét" -> "Exemple concret".

Wouldn't this be that old thing about service in French?  S'il s'avère nécessaire, je pourrais vous rendre ce/un service etc. [This is a question for Derek, not an answer]

@FrançoisJurain Où as-tu entendu/vu "je vous défraierai"?

@Frank dans le dico. OEuf corse. Partout où ya des frais, on défraie. Partout où ya des honoraires, on honore.

@FrançoisJurain Y'a des frais ou des honoraires dans "I'd be happy to..."? Je vois bien l'exemple de Derek, mais je trouve qu'on s'éloigne du titre qui n'est pas forcément une question de sous.

??? Y'a des frais dans "I would thus be happy to pay extra fees for your time". Elle est pas de moi cette phrase, c'est l"exemple concret" (ou concrét) de l'OP.

Et ya des frais dans la traduction française qu'il propose: "je serais donc heureux de payer des frais supplémentaires pour votre temps." C quoi le pb?

Pour la 1ère phrase, je souscris à la proposition de @Bruno. Pour la 2ème, on peut dire "il me semble opportun de consacrer des moyens supplémentaires pour couvrir vos prestations".

@FrançoisJurain L'OP s'inquiète de savoir s'il peut dire "heureux de" dans la conclusion, qui reprend le titre, et l'exemple, ... n'est qu'un exemple, pas à mon avis le focus de la question. Défrayer ne s'applique ni à "would be happy to", ni à "heureux de".

Dans ces situations on emploie souvent l'expression "je me tiens à votre disposition pour..." afin de signifier qu'on est prêt à faire quelque chose à la demande de son interlocuteur. – Bruno
"Il est clair que cette demande nécessitera diverses recherches de votre part: je vous défraierai {volontiers | bien volontiers} du temps que vous y consacrerez." – François Jurain
"Il me semble opportun de consacrer des moyens supplémentaires pour couvrir vos prestations". – Graffito

Je vous défraierai me semble un peu précieux.

Cette réponse avec le verbe défrayer n'est pas le même registre que l'anglais.

@Lambie N'est pas du même registre, on est bien d'accord. La question porte cependant sur "would be happy" traduit par "(bien) volontiers" ou "opportun" par les contributeurs de cette réponse.

Non, would be happy n'est pas bien volontiers. Il faut un verbe, et pas défrayer.

@Lambie N'hésite pas à contribuer.
